# deno upgrade shows the error 'Cannot resolve module upgrade'

Tags: deno

```
deno upgrade
Cannot resolve module "file:///Users/wangjintao/upgrade"
```

when I run 'deno upgrade' and then show me 'Cannot resolve module'.
how to fix it?
thank you

I install deno use

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
```

deno --version is 0.35 I want update it to 1.0.0

env: macOs 10.15.5
and the i try agin run the follow command

```
curl -fsSL https://x.deno.js.cn/install.sh | sh -s v1.0.0
```

but the Deno's version still 0.35. May be i should remove deno first and then reinstall. but i hate myself. i dont know how to uninstall deno.

Comment: a few moments later :)    the mirror image https://github.com/denocn/deno_install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an old version of deno installed that does not have `upgrade` command. Install the latest Deno version, after that you'll be able to do: `deno upgrade` for future releases.

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
```

To uninstall `deno` you can issue the following command:

```
rm `which deno`
# rm $(which deno)
```

Comment: thank you.   but if I run your Command I will install version 0.35. because your install deno command is same to me

Comment: That command installs the latest deno version. Have you run it?

Comment: doing...  i am in china you know the network is slow slow shit. mey be after 30 min. i will tell you the result. and now is 10% and now is 15% don't amazed

Comment: i at list (finely) fix it , i use brew uninstall the deno and install v1.0.0 by mirror image.and now i am upgradeing it to 1.2.0. thank for your help!!!